# Django ForeignKey model not working with serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to build a django app that takes a record file as an uploaded file and then generates data for that record file and saves it to a local directory in the "server" local pc at the moment so for now i have this:

models.py:

```
class Sensor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    OwnerCompany = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Bag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sensor = models.ForeignKey("Sensor",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    bag_file = models.FileField(upload_to="bag_files/")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

views.py :

```
class BagView(APIView): #to be changed to viewset
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    def get(self, request):
        bags = Bag.objects.all()
        serializer = BagSerializer(bags, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request):
        print(request.FILES,request.data)
        serializer = BagSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            bag_upload = request.FILES['bag_upload']
            if bag_upload:
                bag_name = os.path.basename(bag_upload.name)
                serializer.create(serializer.validated_data,bag_name)
                return Response({'message': 'Bag File Created and Data Extracted', 'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializers.py :

```
class SensorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Sensor
        fields = "__all__"
    

class BagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bag_upload = serializers.FileField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bag
        fields = ['id', 'sensor', 'date_created', 'bag_upload']

    def create(self, validated_data,bag_name):
        print("HIIII")
        bag_upload = validated_data.pop('bag_upload', None)
        sensor_data = validated_data.pop('sensor', None)  # Get 'sensor' data from validated data
        print(sensor_data)
        bag_name = bag_name

        # Check if 'sensor' data is provided
        if sensor_data is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Sensor data is required")

        sensor_instance,created = Sensor.objects.get_or_create(name=sensor_data.name)
        # Get or create the sensor instance
        # bag_instance = Bag.objects.create(name=bag_name, sensor=sensor_instance, **validated_data)
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
            for chunk in bag_upload.chunks():
                temp_file.write(chunk)
            temp_file_path = temp_file.name


        extracted_data = ExtractDataFrame(sensor_data.name,temp_file_path).to_csv(os.path.join(settings.SAVED_CSV_ROOT,f"{bag_name}.csv"),sep=';')
        bag_instance = Bag(name=bag_name, bag_file=extracted_data, **validated_data)
        bag_instance.sensor = sensor_instance
        bag_instance.save()
        return bag_instance
```

so what i am trying to do is that whenever a person upload a reocrd file they have to mention a sensor related to that record file in the frontend and using a curl method as follows:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/Bag/ \    -F "bag_upload=@30kph-medium.2024-03-01.15-39-16.11.bagtmp;filename=30kph-medium.2024-03-01.15-39-16.11.bagtmp" \    -F "sensor=1" \    -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
```

this command here works fine and upload the file generates the data using the ExtractDataframe function but then when i try to pass the sensor instance to the bag_instance i get this error:

> KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field
> `sensor` on serializer `BagSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be
> named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the
> `OrderedDict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'sensor'."

i don't know why exactly although i made sure that sensor_instance is an instance of the class model Sensor. it also happend when i use `sensor = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Sensor.objects.all(), source='sensor_id')`
in the Bag serializer i just don't get the error it doesn't say anything

anybody can help me with this please i would really appreciate it

Comment: Check the spelling of the fields in the uploaded data. In the `curl` command you have "sensor" with lower case leading **"s"**. in the models you have "Sensor" with upper case leading **"S"**.

Comment: but when i use the curl command and then i want to retrieve the Sensor.objects.get() using the data i posted with curl it works fine, sensor field is an object of the class Bag that is a ForeignKey connected to model Sensor i don't think it's that causing the problem ? just assuming of course i am not sure

Comment: You will not get very far in software development by "just assuming". You need to check the actual values of all the data that is being processed at the time of the error.

Comment: To figure out the issue, `dir(BagSerializer)` it will show you all the available fields, also since BagSerializer has Sensor as foreign key so, in request data you should pass `sensor_id` not `sensor`. Since when you are creating an Bag instance and providing sensor, it will try to link the existing sensor instead of creating new.

Comment: by just assuming i meant im assuming that the problem is not coming from the case sensitive issue. Finally i found the problem, the problem was that i was trying to create an instance of Bag model and i realized that it was creating but the bag_instance.save() method was raising the error because i am popping the values from validated data which turns it to an empty dict and then the .save() method fails, so what i did is i removed the .save() method and replace Bag(name=....) with Bag.objects.create(...) and changed valdiated_data.pop with .get and now i am able to post and save data to DB